# Sorting Unanswered Questions by Vote does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, unanswered-questions, sorting, votes-tab

(This problem appears nondeterministically, but frequently. So you might not see what I am seeing when you read this question!)

I often observe that the list appearing under

https://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes

is ordered in a strange way. For instance, at the moment of writing this the highest-voted question is on page 4.

Usually, this goes away after a few minutes, but at this moment, it seems to be like this at least for 12 hours.

Is there a problem with index generation, or is this to be expected, or can I do something to "refresh" the ordering?

**Edit:** Things seem to have been shuffled a bit. Now the highest-voted question is on page <strike>6</strike> 9 when I open the link.

Comment: @PolyGeo Have you flipped to page 4? There's a question with 33 votes there.

Comment: I notice that the 33 vote question was protected by Community on May 27 so maybe that is preventing/upsetting the expected sort.

Comment: @PolyGeo Might be. Note that everything after the 33 vote question appears to be correctly ordered, while all the questions before are ordered in themselves, but are the newest ones. So there seem to be two "clusters", for whatever reason. I don't know whether the protection you observed can cause this, but would this mean it's a resident problem? As I said above, I frequently observe "loss" of ordering in this list, but it's usually quite temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marc Gravell kicked the tag engine that powers the list, so it should be properly ordered now.

Comment: Indeed :-)  Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: @StephanLehmke Under normal circumstances, this shouldn't be needed, so you could say it's already automated. :)

Comment: As I said, I frequently observe this (though never so far for such a long period of time). Should I report here every time?

Comment: @StephanLehmke If you see it stay wrong for a day or two, report it. You can report on TeX meta as well, doesn't have to be here.

Comment: Great, I'll do that then :-)